# Applying the patch command using files in different directories in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, diff, command, patch

I'm trying to apply a patch using 2 files in different directories. The output file should be in a different directory too. The first file is in **/var/local/documents/document.xml** and patch file is located in **/var/local/patches/patch.diff** and I want the output file should be created in **/var/local/final/final.xml**.

When the files are located in the same directory, this command works:

```
patch document.xml -i patch.diff -o final.xml
```

But when they are in separate directories and I try to use the following command:

> patch
>   /var/local/documents/document.xml -i
>   /var/local/patches/patch.diff -o
>   /var/local/final/final.xml

I get the following error:

```
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file {file}
Hunk#1 FAILED at 20.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file {file}
```

I've read somewhere that I should use -d and -p to work correctly with directories but I have no clue how I should do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's **-p** switch (in your case it should strip 2 entries from patch path):

```
cd /var/local/documents
patch -p 2 -o ../final/final.xml document.xml < ../patches/patch.diff
```

Comment: Thank you :) What should the patch command look like if the the patch file was /var/local/out/upload/patch.patch and both the final file and the original file were /var/local/upload/example_word/word/document.xml?

Comment: Considering you are in `/var/local/upload/example_word/word` it would be `patch -o final.xml -p 4 document.xml < /var/local/out/upload/patch.patch`; [var] + [local] + [out] + [upload] == 4, hence `-p 4`

Comment: Or `patch -o final.xml -p 5 document.xml < ../../../out/upload/patch.patch` ([..] + [..] + [..] + [out] + [upload] == 5) with relative paths.

Comment: @wilsonsilva: you should be in `/var/local/upload/example_word/word` i.e. `cd` to this directory before applying the patch.

Comment: I did that. I want to apply the patch located in /var/local/out/upload/patch.patch to the file /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word/document.xml forget about the final.xml. This is what I did: cd /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word and then patch -p 2 document.xml < ../../patch.patch but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @wilsonsilva: and it shouldn't ('cause of improper path to "patch.patch"); it should be `patch -p 4 document.xml < /var/local/out/upload/patch.patch`, see my comment on counting `p` value.

Comment: @wilsonsilva: `..` means "one level up", i.e. in your case path "../.." resolves to "/var/local/upload" (and your patch is in different directory)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ mv /var/local/final/final.xml /var/local/final/document.xml
$ (cd /var/local/final && patch document.xml) < patch.diff
$ mv /var/local/final/document.xml /var/local/final/final.xml
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice workaround and I thought about it too I needed to patch without moving the files.